# Making precise Dehn filling

Tags: manifolds, knot-theory, surgery-theory

Dehn surgery along a knot is a well-known construction: choose a regular neighbourhood $N(K)$ of a knot $K \subset S^3$, let $X_K := S^3 - N(K)$ and choose an essential simple closed curve $\alpha$ on the torus $\partial X_K$.

Then surgery along $K$ is the pushout $X_K \cup_\varphi S^1 \times D^2$. In the literature it is common to find that the attaching map $\varphi : S^1 \times \partial D^2 \to \partial X_K$ is completely determined by mapping the meridian $* \times \partial D^2$ to $\alpha$. How to make precise that such assignment extends to the required map $\varphi$?

Answer (score 3):

One way to see that the image of the meridian determines how to attach the entire torus is by first gluing in a thickened disk, then a 3-ball (which gives the entire torus).

More precisely, first attach a $D^2 \times I$ to $X_K$ via a homeomorphism $f: (\partial D^2 \times I) \to N(\alpha)$, where $N(\alpha)$ is a regular neighborhood of $\alpha$ in $\partial X_K$. This step is just identifying two cylinders.

We then have a 3-manifold $X_K \cup_f (D^2 \times I)$ which has an $S^2$ boundary. Attaching a $D^3$ via a homeomorphism of the $S^2$ boundaries gives a closed 3-manifold.

Here the $D^3$ and the $D^2 \times I$ combined form the total $S^1 \times D^2$ you are gluing in.

As a final note, the resulting 3-manifold does not depend (up to homeomorphism) on the choices of homeomorphisms for gluing, for example since the mapping class groups of $S^1$ and $S^2$ are trivial. See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1512919/to-define-dehn-surgery-should-one-allow-orientation-reversing-diffeomorphisms-o?rq=1).

Comment: Okay so via this argument one has specify a "fattened" characteristic map $\chi: D^2 \times I \to X_K$ , consider the intermediate manifold $X_K \cup_f (D^2 \times I)$ and later extend it to the required $\varphi$. However is there a way of getting $\varphi$ without an intermediate glueing? For instance using obstruction theory or a similar tool?

Comment: This argument is just a way of seeing that $\varphi$ exists, but you can glue it all at once without this intermediate step if you want to. You might also be interested in looking at the mapping class group of the torus to see all possible ways to glue two 3-manifolds with torus boundary.

Comment: I am much happier with an argument invoking the isomorphism $MCG(S^1 \times S^1) \cong SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$. Thanks!